# How to change content of recyclerview Item from another activity

Tags: android

How to change content of recyclerview Item from another activity, i need suggestions and want to know what is best way to achieve this

Comment: Simply use `Interface` or `Broadcast`.

Comment: Always post your code to get help based on it. Show your effort. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use either interface or LocalBroadcastManager for this, checkout below link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html